body.getHtm() is throwing error in word add-ins
We have integrated word add-ins in our application through WOPI. body.getHtm() was working a week before but now it is throwing errors.
enter image description here
await Word.run(async (context) => {
  const body = context.document.body;
  const bodyHTML = body.getHtml();
  await context.sync();
  var HTMLContent = bodyHTML.value
})

